# Can MacOS app to create a new file in Bundle.main?

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way for a MacOS app to create a new file in Bundle.main?

It seems like "Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "json")" is read only. I can find the file in main bundle and read the content. However, when I try to create a file, it says the app doesn't have permission.

However, it tseems like I can create/read/write in "FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last".

Is there a way to make a contained portable app where if you copy the app to another computer, it brings all the modified data with you? If the app could create/read/write a file inside .app package, that would be ideal. I don't think documentDirectory travels if you just copy the .app, right, right?

Comment: i think it's not possible

Comment: @vadian, you marked this question as duplicate, but where's the link for the question?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's read-only. Bundles are important for signing/verifying/updating your application, it shouldn't be messed up. Yep, stick on [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) within `.documentDirectory`.

Comment: Is there any way to make a contained portable app where if you copy the app to another computer without icloud sync, it brings all the modified data with you?